# Can the isometry group of the set of zeros of an L-function $F$ be used to make $F$ automorphic?

Tags: nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, selberg-class

I'm still trying to understand the notion of automorphic (L-)function. Due to my lack of knowledge of the subject, this question may appear pretty vague and therefore may not be suitable for MO. I apologize for that.
So judging by what I read in Wikipedia, given a group $G$ acting on a complex manifold $X$, $G$ acts on the space of holomorphic functions from $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$. For any element $F$ of the Selberg class $\mathcal{S}$, let's take for $X$ the (possibly compactified) critical strip $\{z\in\mathbb{C},0<\Re(z)<1\}$ and for $G$ the isometry group of the set of zeros of $F$: $G$ is a subgroup of the group $(\{id,z\mapsto \bar{z},z\mapsto 1-z, z\mapsto 1-\bar{z}\},\circ)$, the latter being isomorphic to the Klein group. Hence $G$ is a discrete group. Moreover $F$ is holomorphic on $X$, so that, if I'm not mistaken, any element $g$ of $G$ maps $F$ to a holomorphic function defined on $X$.

Now, whenever $z$ is a zero of $F$, one has, for all $g\in G$ acting naturally on $X$, $F(g.z)=F(z)=0$. So is there some kind of "factor of automorphy" $j_{g}$ such that $F(g.z)=j_{g}(z)F(z)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question seems rather tautological.  For example, if $g = (z \mapsto 1-\bar{z})$, then $j_g(z)$ is determined by the functional equation.

Comment: Whatever is the Selberg class, how can $z \mapsto \bar{z}$ map a (nonconstant) holomorphic function to a holomorphic function?

Answer (score 2):

You are asking the wrong question concerning the "automorphy factor."  There is no deep information to be extracted from thinking about some abstract group action on a space of functions.  All the information relevant to your question is just sitting there in the functional equation.

You say that "$z\to\overline{z}$ is an isometry of the zeros."  How do you intend that map to act on $F$?  If you send $F(z)$ to $F(\overline{z})$ then you have not mapped a holomorphic function to a holomorphic function.

More importantly, if $F$ does not have real Dirichlet coefficients, then the zeros are not closed under conjugation.  The set of symmetries of the critical zeros of an L-function has either 2 elements (id and $z\to 1-\overline{z}$ in the case of non-real coefficients), or 4 elements (the 4 you list).  All this is just the Schwartz reflection principle.

Let $\Lambda(s) = A(s) F(s)$ be the completed L-function, where $A(s)$ involves the $\Gamma$-function and powers of 2 and $\pi$.  Apologies for the nonstandard notation but I didn't want to re-name symbols used in the question. So it satisfies the functional equation $\Lambda(s) = \epsilon \overline{\Lambda}(1-s)$. Here $\overline{\Lambda}(z)$ means $\overline{\Lambda(\overline{z})}$.  That conjugation is the point of what I wrote in the previous paragraph.

Everything about your question just comes from the functional equation and complex analysis facts about conjugation.  You can rearrange the functional equation to appear in a form similar to the last equation in your question, but nothing has been gained, and the notation (designed to look like something from modular forms) is probably not helpful.